# Spring multiple OAuth2 authorization servers with Eureka

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, authorization, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I'm currently developing an application with a micro-service architecture back-end using Spring. We are using Zuul+Eureka for load balancing and service discovery and OAuth2 for authorization.

Is it possible to route requests to the OAuth2 endpoints on the authorization server through zuul? We want to do this in order to support multiple authorization server instances, but the problem is that as far as I know I have to provide a URI to the following config properties:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      ...
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:3001/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:3001/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:3001/oauth/check_token
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:3001/user
```

So my question is if this is even possible with a `OAuth2SSoClient` server or if we should do this via another way, such as a server-side load balancer.